# Why is MonadIO specific to IO, rather than a more generic MonadTrans?

Tags: haskell, types, io, monad-transformers

So in `transformers` I see,

```hs
class (Monad m) => MonadIO m where
    -- | Lift a computation from the 'IO' monad.
    liftIO :: IO a -> m a

instance MonadIO IO where
    liftIO = id
```

and I understand that the reason that this differs from MonadTrans is that if you have some `M1T (M2T (M3T (M4T IO))) x` made of 4 composed monad transformers, then you don't want to `lift . lift . lift . lift $ putStrLn "abc"` but you'd rather just `liftIO $ putStrLn "abc"`.

But, this specificity for `IO` seems very weird when the fundamental definition above seems to be this weird set of recursions with `liftIO`. It seems like there should either be a newtype declaration for some combinator like `(ExceptT :~: MaybeT) IO x` so that a single `lift` is all you ever need (I suppose this is a monad transformer transformer?), or else some multi-param type class,

```
class (Monad m) => MonadEmbed e m
    -- | Lift a computation from the `e` monad.
    embed :: e a -> m a

instance (Monad m) => MonadEmbed m m where
     embed = id
```

Why doesn't `transformers` use one of these approaches so that the MonadTrans sequences do not have to be rooted in `IO`? Is it just the fact that the transformers handle all "other" effects so that the only things at the very bottom are either `Identity` (already handled with `return :: a -> m a`) or `IO`? Or does the above require something like UndecidableInstances which the `transformers` library is loathe to include? Or what?

Comment: AFAIK `transformers` is Haskell 98 which does **not** include multiparameter type classes, so your example "isn't allowed" according to this restriction.  The `mtl` library provides some typeclasses like `MonadState` and a few instances that allow you to avoid lifting many times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But, this specificity for `IO` seems very weird

I challenge the assumption that this is specific to `IO`. I also see many other classes in `mtl`. For example:

```
class Monad m => MonadError e m | m -> e where
    throwError :: e -> m a
    catchError :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a

class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    get :: m s
    put :: s -> m ()
    state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
```

...and many others. Generally, the "`mtl` way" to build monadic actions is to use these typeclass-polymorphic operations, so that one need never `lift` -- rather, just monomorph the operation to the appropriate lifted type. For example, `MonadError` completely replaces a hypothetical `liftMaybe :: MonadMaybe m => Maybe a -> m a`: rather than lifting a `Maybe a` value, one would have the producer of the `Maybe a` value call `throwError` and `return` instead of `Nothing` and `Just`.

> It seems like there should be a newtype declaration for some combinator like `(ExceptT :~: MaybeT) IO x` so that a single lift is all you ever need

With this proposal, you would need (at least) two different *kinds* of lifts: one lift to go from `m a` to `trans m a`, and one lift to go from `trans m a` to `(trans' :~: trans) m a`. Having a single operation that handles both kinds of lifting is more uniform.

> It seems like there should be some multi-param type class,
>
> ```
> class Monad m => MonadEmbed e m
>     -- | Lift a computation from the `e` monad.
>     embed :: e a -> m a
>
> instance Monad m => MonadEmbed m m where
>     embed = id
> ```

This approach looks deceptively nice at first. However, if you try to write and use this class, you will quickly discover why all the `mtl` classes include functional dependencies: the instance `MonadEmbed m m` is surprisingly hard to choose! Even a very simple example like

```
embed (Right ()) :: Either String ()
```

is an ambiguity error. (After all, we only know that `Right 3 :: Either a ()` for some `a` -- we don't yet know that `a ~ String` and so we can't choose the `MonadEmbed m m` instance!) I suspect most of your other instances will run into similar problems. If you add the obvious functional dependencies, your type inference problems go away but the fundep checks greatly restrict you: one may only lift from the base monad and not from arbitrary intermediate monads as you might hope. This is such a painful problem in practice (and the "`mtl` way" pain is so small) that it isn't done in `mtl`.

That said, you may enjoy using the [`transformers-base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-base-0.4.4/docs/Control-Monad-Base.html) package.

> Is it just the fact that the transformers handle all "other" effects so that the only things at the very bottom are either `Identity` (already handled with `return :: a -> m a`) or `IO`?

As you say, the most common bases are `IO` (for which we already have `MonadIO`) or `Identity` (for which one generally just uses `return` and a pure computation rather than a lifted monadic computation). Sometimes `ST` is a handy base monad, but it is a bit more rare to use transformers over `ST` than it is to use them over `IO`.

Answer (score 5):

The `Monad...` classes seem designed mostly to *directly generalise* the characteristic operations of a monad to also work if that monad is buried under a stack of transformers. These operations are normally not such a big set, e.g. `State` simply needs [`get`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:get), [`put`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:put), `state` and  `modify` if you want, but that's it.

Not so with `IO`; it would be rather impractical to make the plethora of fundamental IO operations methods of the `MonadIO` class. You can of course get *all* of them though, if you just introduce `liftIO` as a “conversion function”, but I'd wager this was always considered a bit of a hack.

Besides: `IO` is the most important non-trivial base monad; I wouldn't consider it inappropriate to give it a dedicated lift function only for that reason.

Regarding your “single lift is all you ever need” idea: the problem with `:~:` is that the transformers now form a binary tree rather than a simple stack with clear hierarchy. This makes the entire idea of the mtl classes much more problematic.